# Timeout during indexing view in Azure Search despite settings

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm using Azure Search Indexer to index a view from Azure SQL DB.

I've created Data Source (view) and set such settings in connection string
`(...)Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=1200;" },`

The indexer still returns timeouts and I see from Azure SQL DB logs, that Indexer's query gets cancelled after 30 seconds:

- ActionStatus: Cancellation
- Statement: SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NO_BROWSETABLE ON;SELECT * FROM
  [dbo].[v_XXX] ORDER BY [rowVersion] SET NO_BROWSETABLE OFF
- ServerDuration: 00:00:30.3559524

The same statement takes ~2 minutes when run through SQL Server Mgmt Studio and gets completed.

I wonder if there may be any other settings (server or DB) that overwrite my connection timeout preferences? If yes, then why there is no timeout when I query my DB using SSMS and there is timeout when Indexer tries to index the view?

Comment: Until we can increase the command timeout, you can try creating an index on the ROWVERSION column, which should speed up the query as long as you don't have a huge number of rows. Indexes on ROWVERSION-style columns are painful though (they churn a lot since each update changes the page a given record goes), but if indexing performance is important it could be an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timeout that cancels the operation is the command timeout, not the connection timeout. The default command timeout used to be 30 seconds, and currently there is no way to change it. We have increased the default command timeout to a much larger value (5 minutes) to mitigate this in the short term. Longer term, we will add the ability to specify a command timeout in the data source definition.

Comment: Any news regarding this feature. I have the same problem at the moment where the view created for the index is quite big and a full "select all" from it takes 12+ minutes.

Comment: We haven't prioritized this feature because in most cases, customers were able to create indexes to optimize their queries. We recommend trying to speed up the query - please reach out to me directly (eugenesh at the usual Microsoft domain) if that doesn't work for you. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I did end up optimizing the query in the end (and removing irrelevant data).

Comment: This is impacting some of Azure's own services, for example when you try to import SQL DB data into an Azure Search index (using the "import" button in the Portal). Azure Search uses the supplied connection string and there is no way to parameterize the command timeout, so it will Timeout eventually, almost everytime. Tried this even in my Standard S3 database (100 DTUs)! No idea how to import my data into the Azure Search now... =/

Comment: We're making the timeout customizable, so customers will be able to increase it from the current value of 5 minutes. This should be available in the next 3 weeks or so.

Comment: Hi @EugeneShvets-MSFT, my query is very simple so there is not much scope for optimization, its only that the command works fine when I don't have a watermark column specified but command timeout occurs when I have a watermark column. Can you please share an update on where we are with a Command Timeout? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Now there is a setting on the indexer. With it you can configure the queryTimeout. I think it is in minutes. My indexer runs now longer then 20 minutes without error.

```
    "startTime": "2016-01-01T00:00:00Z"
  },
  "parameters": {
    "batchSize": null,
    "maxFailedItems": 0,
    "maxFailedItemsPerBatch": 0,
    "base64EncodeKeys": false,
    "configuration": {
      "queryTimeout": "360"
    }
  },
  "fieldMappings": [
    {
```

**Update**: At the moment it can not be set over the azure portal. You can set it via the [REST Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/update-indexer):

```
PUT https://[service name].search.windows.net/indexers/[indexer name]?api-version=[api-version]  
Content-Type: application/json  
api-key: [admin key]
```

Comment: Hi @Magu, how do you specify this using the Azure Portal interface?

Comment: @Diceyus I update my answer and include a link to the rest api doc

Comment: QueryTimeout should be 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

Use the REST API link https://[SERVICE].search.windows.net/indexers/[Indexer]?api-version=2016-09-01 to get the Indexer definition and then use a POST to the same address to update it.

Ref [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers#configuration-settings)

Answer (score 0):

Timeout can be changed if you select "Indexer Definition (JSON)" and insert
`"queryTimeout": "hh:mm:ss"` in the `configuration` attribute.

The value must be on the `hh:mm:ss` format and less than 24 hours.
The default is 5 minutes.
For 10 minutes use:

```json
"configuration": {
      "queryTimeout": "00:10:00"
    }
```